# What happens under the hood when I use supervisorctl stop [running-program]?

Tags: supervisord

I have 2 bash scripts

1. starts `celery worker` (celery worker ...)
2. starts `jupyter lab` (set some ENV vars and run jupyter lab)

and I setup supervisor for them.

When I use 
`supervisorctl stop [program]`
the 1st program is properly stopped but the 2nd program continues running even when supervisor told me that the program is stopped.

What happened under the hood that cause `supervisorctl stop` to have this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

in your .conf file, if you don't set the stopsignal, the signal is TERM by default, and kill pid use TERM as default signal too. so maybe supervisorctl stop just means kill.